# AngularJS - $compile is not defined in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to run this command in ng-click:

```
formFieldTemplate='<element fieldvalue="' + $( "#"+name+"Div").attr('fieldvalue') + '" name="' + $( "#"+name+"Div").attr('name') +'[' + dynamic_count + ']" value="' + $( "#"+name+"Div").attr('value') + '" ' + 'fieldvisible="' + $("#"+name+"Div").attr('fieldvisible') + '" type="' + $( "#"+name+"Div").attr('type') + '" useredit="' + $( "#"+name+"Div").attr('useredit') + '"></element>'
$compile(formFieldTemplate)($scope); 
$( "#"+name+"Div").append(formFieldTemplate);
```

I get this error:

> $compile is not defined

Can someone please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Wait, you're trying to run that entire command in ng-click, or are you referencing a function?

Comment: I'm doing it in ng-click

Comment: where did you are executing this code? Inside a controller or directive?

Comment: is compile defined in you controller ?

Comment: Thenk you, it worked.

Comment: but why is the directive not working on the new element?

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer your question, you need to ensure that your $compileProvider is injected into module and then is provided to your directive/controller. It seems based on what you've provided that you are putting into a directive? That would be the best place to do something like this (IMHO). See the angular api [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling it in a directive, you must pass the **$compile** parameter,

Example:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {

 // Your directive code


};
```